# Download Maps for Windows Store app 8.1

Tags: c#, maps, windows-8.1, openstreetmap

I am developing a Windows app (8.1, no Runtime, no Phone) showing OSM Maps. I have installed the Bing SDK and now the app is correctly showing online maps with OSM tiles.

I have to let the user download these maps for offline use.
So far I have found that the [MapService class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.services.maps.mapservice.aspx), that communicates with the online service, is available only for Runtime apps, but I haven't been able to find an alternative to this API.

Is there any documentation or something similar for my issue. Is it possible to achieve my goal? Since I am not an expert, am I looking in the wrong direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no service offering bulk downloading of OSM [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles). The reason for this is that this is a very heavy, ressource-intensive task. You can try to talk with one of the many [tile providers](https://switch2osm.org/providers/) or [run your own tile server](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using OSM I recommend you to check out the official OSM APIs for doing tile rendering and map downloads. You can find them here:

- http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6
- http://openstreetmap.us/~migurski/vector-datasource/
- http://www.free-map.org.uk/0.6/about.html#developer

Comment: This API offers neither rendered maps nor map downloads. It is for *editing* the map only.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in the first link I can't see any reference for dowloading any map, the third solution is available only for UK country. In the second link I can't find any reference to the "standard" OSM Layer, am I wrong?

Comment: Well these links are tutorials to ways how you can host your own renderservice. Check this: http://developer.skobbler.de/ if you want to use a "renderservice" it's free for apps with a small amount of requests.